# MSSQL: SSIS 2005 transfer logins task

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I created an SSIS package to transfer logins from one server to another in SQL 2005 SSIS project using BIDS.

I want to transfer all packages but skip 3. So I changed the maximum number of error count to 3. But it didn't help.

can anyone please help me in achieving this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just script them out with sp_help_revlogin?

Comment: I found that sp_help_revlogin doesn't copy server roles across. + I need to run this on daily basis. Any comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work around- used dynamic sql to capture all logins, stored it into a temporary table. Scripted out for the ones needed and then ran executesql.